# how to get UAprof url for samsung mobile

Tags: android, mobile-devices, capability, device-detection, uaprof

when i connect to the servlet from my andoid mobile browser I need to get UAprof url for my samsung mobile in x-wap-profile headers but im not getting the header ...

but when i tried to connect the servlet from htc i could to get uaprof url in X-Wap-Profile header..how should i get uaprof url for my samsung mobile please help me..

thanks in advance..

Comment: isn't the UAProf declared FROM your handset in the HTTP header?

Comment: I get an x-wap-profile header out of my Samsung Galaxy S, based on what I'm seeing at http://whatsmyuseragent.com What headers are you seeing?

Comment: No i havent declared UAprof in my handset how to declare it ???

Comment: I used headers like "X-Wap-Profile" useragent Profile and also accept

Answer (score 0):

UAProf document of a mobile device can very often be found in the HTTP headers **x-wap-profile** or **Profile**, otherwise you can check the **Opt** headers. See this [UAProf info](http://www.developershome.com/wap/detection/detection.asp?page=uaprof) for more information.

Here is an  [example UAProf document](http://nds1.nds.nokia.com/uaprof/N6230ir200.xml) for a nokia

It seems not all devices will provide these headers, which I guess is the problem you are having.

You could also search for it manually on http://www.uaprof.com/

There are other ways to find device capabilities, for example have a look at the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) xml document which lists many devices and capabilities.

At the moment I am using the WURFL and looking for the device by User Agent string provided, but in some cases the device is missing or a new update has come out affecting the user agent string and it has not been added into the WURFL release yet.  So still a fallback needs to be considered... partial user agent string match? UAProf?